# Airflow: How to push xcom value from PostgreOperator?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I'm using Airflow 1.8.1 and I want to push the result of a sql request from PostgreOperator.

Here's my tasks:

```
check_task = PostgresOperator(
    task_id='check_task',
    postgres_conn_id='conx',
    sql="check_task.sql",
    xcom_push=True,
    dag=dag)

def py_is_first_execution(**kwargs):
    value = kwargs['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='check_task')
    print 'count ----> ', value
    if value == 0:
       return 'next_task'
    else:
       return 'end-flow'

check_branch = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='is-first-execution',
    python_callable=py_is_first_execution,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)
```

and here is my sql script:

```
select count(1) from table
```

when i check the xcom value from `check_task` it retrieves `none` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I created a new Sensor `ExecuteSqlOperator` in the plugin manager under `$AIRFLOW_HOME/plugins`.

I used `CheckOperator` as an example and I modified the returned value: the basic running of this operator was exactly the reverse of what I needed.

Here's the of the default `ExecuteSqlOperator`:
[CheckOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/operators/check_operator.py)

and here is my customized `SqlSensor`: `ReverseSqlSensor`

```
class SqlExecuteOperator(BaseOperator):
    """
    Performs checks against a db. The ``CheckOperator`` expects
    a sql query that will return a single row.

    Note that this is an abstract class and get_db_hook
    needs to be defined. Whereas a get_db_hook is hook that gets a
    single record from an external source.
    :param sql: the sql to be executed
    :type sql: string
    """

    template_fields = ('sql',)
    template_ext = ('.hql', '.sql',)
    ui_color = '#fff7e6'

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(
            self, sql,
            conn_id=None,
            *args, **kwargs):
        super(SqlExecuteOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.conn_id = conn_id
        self.sql = sql

    def execute(self, context=None):
        logging.info('Executing SQL statement: ' + self.sql)
        records = self.get_db_hook().get_first(self.sql)
        logging.info("Record: " + str(records))
        records_int = int(records[0])
        print (records_int)
        return records_int

    def get_db_hook(self):
        return BaseHook.get_hook(conn_id=self.conn_id)
```

Answer (score 12):

If i'm correct, airflow automatically pushes to xcom when a query returns a value. However, when you look at the code of the [postgresoperator](https://pythonhosted.org/airflow/_modules/postgres_operator.html) you see that it has an execute method that calls the run method of the PostgresHook (extension of dbapi_hook). Both methods do not return anything, as such it pushes nothing to xcom. 
What we did to fix this is create a CustomPostgresSelectOperator, a copy of the PostgresOperator, but instead of 'hook.run(..)' do 'return hook.get_records(..)'.

Hope that helps you.

Comment: And does it work for different processes in airflow cluster?
I tried with this: https://gist.github.com/fpopic/35807489d9c36c7ea8bc4de6f966b5fc#file-select_postgres_operator-py-L38-L42

but if the next operator in dag uses the result that SelectPostgresOperator.execute returns I always got some exception, so what is the preferred way to do it? I see a lot of operators like A_to_B to put all logic (probably input/output hooks) in one operator to avoid sharing state (that might be big) between multiple processes.