# How to pass the result from first query to the second one with PostgresOperator in airflow 2.x?

Tags: postgresql, airflow, airflow-2.x

I have to pass the result of my first redshift query to the second one. I am using postgres operator, Postgre script. doesn't have any return function as you see in this [link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-postgres/stable/_modules/airflow/providers/postgres/operators/postgres.html#PostgresOperator)

Actually I thought to modify the script and add return to the execute method. But the point is that I do not use the execute method and for executing the sql script I am using this:

```
retrieve_latest_query_task = PostgresOperator(
            sql='rs_warm-up_query-id.sql',
            postgres_conn_id='redshift',
            task_id='retrieve_latest_query_ids_from_metadata'
        )
```

Here are my two queries:

```
SELECT query
FROM (SELECT query,
             querytxt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY querytxt ORDER BY query ASC) AS num
      FROM stl_query
      WHERE userid = 102
      AND   starttime >= CURRENT_DATE - 2 + INTERVAL '7 hour'
      AND   starttime < CURRENT_DATE - 2 + INTERVAL '11 hour'
      AND   UPPER(querytxt) LIKE 'SELECT %'
      ORDER BY query)
WHERE num = 1;
```

and with the retrieve data (which is a list) , I have to pass it to the second script:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(CASE WHEN LEN (RTRIM(TEXT)) = 0 THEN TEXT ELSE RTRIM(TEXT) END,'') within group(ORDER BY SEQUENCE) AS TEXT
FROM stl_querytext
WHERE query = {};
```

I thought that using **xcom** could be a good solution, as I don't return many rows. But I don't know how to use it with Postgres.

*I don't want to use the temporal table, as I believe that for that small volume I don't need.*

I ll appreciate your help.

Comment: You'll have to create a custom operator or use PythonOperator. See this other question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45630950/airflow-how-to-push-xcom-value-from-postgreoperator